# Showing that $ \operatorname {Var} ( X ) \le 1 $ when $ | X | \le 1 $ a.s., and that the maximum is attained

Tags: probability, probability-theory, variance, probability-limit-theorems

> A random variable $ X $ satisfies $ | X | \le 1 $ a.s. Show that $ \operatorname {Var} ( X ) \le 1 $, and that the maximum is attained.

I am apply Chebyshev's inequality.

If $ X $ is any random variable, then for any $ b > 0 $ we have
$$ \Pr ( | X − \mathbb E [ X ] | \ge b ) \le \frac { \operatorname {Var} ( X ) } { b ^ 2 } \text , $$
But I am not getting anything please help me how to solve this.

Thank you.

Comment: Use König-Huygen's formula:
$$\mathrm{Var}(X)=\mathbb E[X^2]-\mathbb E[X]^2\le\mathbb E[X^2].$$

Answer (score 4):

Clearly, if $|X| \leq 1$ a.s., then we almost surely have $X^2 \leq 1$.

Therefore, $\mathbb{E}[X^2] \leq 1$, i.e. the second (and therefore also the first) moment of $X$ exists.

So, $0 \leq \mathbf{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - (\mathbb{E}[X])^2 \leq 1 - 0 = 1$,
where we used $(\mathbb{E}[X])^2 \geq 0$ and $\mathbb{E}[X^2] \leq 1$.

Note that $\mathbf{Var}(X)$ is non-negative by definition.

You also attain the bound if $\mathbb{P}(X = 1) = \mathbb{P}(X = -1) = \frac{1}{2} $.

Clearly we would then have $|X| \leq  1$ a.s. and also $\mathbb{E}[X] = 0$.

So, $\mathbf{Var}(X) = \mathbb{E}[X^2] = \mathbb{E}[1] = 1$.